# Error in dplyr when using nested group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I´m trying to carry out several operations using dplyr but I´m stuck and I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

The first fifteen rows of my 60760 observations dataframe looks like this:

```
df <-structure(list(dem_sect = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L),
.Label = c("AB", "EP", "FE", "MF", "PA"), class = "factor"), 
area = c(1181.16, 1181.16, 2190.28, 2190.28, 956.08, 2190.28, 1181.16, 2190.28, 956.08, 2190.28, 2190.28, 1181.16, 2190.28, 956.08, 921.47), 
peso_kg = c(0.184, 0.674, 0.1, 0.152, 0.21, 0.104, 4.31, 0.048, 0.242, 0.724, 0.126, 1.13, 0.13, 0.048, 0.075),
sector = c("MFa", "MFa", "MFb", "MFb", "MFc", "MFb", "MFa", "MFb", "MFc", "MFb", "MFb", "MFa", "MFb", "MFc", "ABb")), 
row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = data.frame")
```

And here it is the code I´m working with

```
test <- df %>% 
group_by(sector) %>%
summarise(md_area= mean (area),
          md_peso= mean (peso_kg),
          se_loc= sqrt(var(peso_kg))/sqrt(length (peso_kg)),
          cv_loc= sd(peso_kg)/ mean (peso_kg)*100) %>%
group_by(dem_sect) %>%
mutate(sum_sect = sum(SEloc * CVloc)))
```

Instead of `mutate(sum_sect = sum(SEloc * CVloc)`, I´ve tried using `mutate(sum_sect=sum(mean(area) * mean(peso_kg))` but in both cases I get the following error:

> Error in `group_by()`:
> ! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
> x Column `dem_sect` is not found.

I tried several approaches but with no success. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.
Any hint will be more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `summarise` takes only those columns that you are grouping by and aggregating by. that is why after summarising RStudio can't find `dem_sect`. try using `mutate` instead of `summarise`; and after mutating by groups, run `ungroup` in order to avoid further errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one observation for every unique value of `dem_sect`, then:

```
test <- df %>%
    group_by(sector) %>%
    mutate(
        md_area = mean(area),
        md_peso = mean(peso_kg),
        se_loc = sqrt(var(peso_kg))/sqrt(length(peso_kg)),
        cv_loc = sd(peso_kg)/mean(peso_kg)*100
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(dem_sect) %>%
    summarize(sum_sect = sum(SEloc * CVloc)))
```

I don't think `SEloc` and `CVloc` exist, should be `se_loc` and `cv_loc`, right?

Comment: you´re right. It was a mistake. I should write se_loc and cv_loc. Thank you for your help. It works.